# Ajax, post data but not callback success

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Yes I know there is so many question like mine, I looked all questions and answers but The solutions is given didn't help me.

I tried to post log-in information to a controller. I got http-200 but ajax success function doesn't called. Instead error function is calling back but it doesn't give a specific error message.

My button code:

```
<button id="loginButton" type="submit" class="btn btn-success pull-right" onclick="login()">Giriş</button>
```

My javascript code:

```
function login () 
    {
        var Name = $("#userName").val();
        var Pssword = $("#userPassword").val();
        var user = 
        {
            'userName': Name,
            'userPassword': Pssword
        };

        jQuery.ajax
        ({
            type:"POST",
            url:"http://localhost:8080/Login/CheckUser",
            dataType: 'html',
            data: user,
            cache: false,
            success: function() {

            alert("hadi ya");

        },
            error: function(httpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
            alert("status=" + textStatus + ",error=" + errorThrown);
            }
        });

    }
```

And my controller code:

```
public function CheckUser()
    {
        $data = $this->input->post();
        $result = $this->LoginModel->CheckUser($data); //returns 1 or nothing
        echo $result;
    }
```

And my model code:

```
function CheckUser($data)
    {
        $this->db->where('userName', $data['userName']);
        $this->db->where('userPassword',$data['userPassword']);
        $query = $this->db->get('users');

        if($query->num_rows == 1)
            return TRUE;
        else 
            return FALSE;
    }
```

I spent whole day for this, What I am doing false?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
/* Change few of your lines: */

<button id="loginButton" type="submit" class="btn btn-success pull-right" onclick="login(event)">Giriş</button>

AND 

function login (e) 
    {
        e.preventDefault();
        var Name = $("#userName").val();
        var Pssword = $("#userPassword").val();
        ...
        and further remains same.
```